# Create new array object from existing object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a json file that's returned from a service am using. I have no control over the service therefore can't change the structure of the json file. The file looks something like:

```
menu":[    
 {
  "section":"theMobileMenu",
  "key":"menuItem1Title",
  "content":"Mobile context and principles"
},
{
  "section":"theMobileMenu",
  "key":"menuItem1Link",
  "content":"/mobile/index.html"
},
{
  "section":"theMobileMenu",
  "key":"menuItem2Title",
  "content":"Global guidelines"
},
{
  "section":"theMobileMenu",
  "key":"menuItem2Link",
  "content":"/mobile/global-guidelines.html"
},
{
  "section":"theMobileMenu",
  "key":"menuItem3Title",
  "content":"First impressions"
},
{
  "section":"theMobileMenu",
  "key":"menuItem3Link",
  "content":"/mobile/first-impressions.html"
}
]
```

I want to create an array of objects like the one below

```
    "menu":[
 {
 "title":"Mobile context and principles",
 "link":"/mobile/index.html"
 },
{
"title":"Global guidelines",
 "link":"/mobile/global-guidelines.html"
},
{
"title":"First impressions",
 "link":"/mobile/first-impressions.html"
}
]
```

I've tried something like:

```
var newData = []
var curData = {};
var x = 1;

$.each(data.menu, function(i, val) {            
    if(val.key == 'menuItem'+x+'Link'){
        curData.link = val.content;         
    }
    if(val.key == 'menuItem'+x+'Title'){
        curData.title = val.content;            
    }
    newData.push(curData)
    curData = []
    x++;            
})
```

This doesn't work very well. Any ideas on how to work this out?

Comment: Please check `data` should be `data.menu`.

Comment: I've edited to data.menu. Doesn't make a difference though

Comment: Is it goes to loop? can you check this?

Comment: @mr_j..is it below cod working?

Comment: your answer returns a blank array. Will's answer works

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var data = [{
    "section": "theMobileMenu",
    "key": "menuItem1Title",
    "content": "Mobile context and principles"
}, {
    "section": "theMobileMenu",
    "key": "menuItem1Link",
    "content": "/mobile/index.html"
}, {
    "section": "theMobileMenu",
    "key": "menuItem2Title",
    "content": "Global guidelines"
}, {
    "section": "theMobileMenu",
    "key": "menuItem2Link",
    "content": "/mobile/global-guidelines.html"
}, {
    "section": "theMobileMenu",
    "key": "menuItem3Title",
    "content": "First impressions"
}, {
    "section": "theMobileMenu",
    "key": "menuItem3Link",
    "content": "/mobile/first-impressions.html"
}];

var obj = {};
var menu = data.map(function(v, k) {
    if (v.key.match(/menuItem\d*Title/) !== null) {
        obj = {
            title: v.content
        };
    } else if (v.key.match(/menuItem\d*Link/) !== null) {
        obj.link = v.content;
        return obj;
    }
});
menu = $.grep(menu, function(n) {
    return n == 0 || n
});
```

The code only works if the keys come in the exact order as shown in the OP.

Comment: This works! Mind giving a quick explanation on how you've done it?

Comment: @mr_j, data is an array, so you can do data.map(function(v) { .... });
Just notice I didn't need the k.  v each object in the original data.  So we test the key, if title, then initialize the obj variable and set the title.  If link, then set the link of the obj variable (at this point, it already has the title set).  Then return the obj.  This return statements returns the object in an array.

When you run data.map, the return is an array of equal length.  If you don't return anything, then you get undefined.

Because of undefined, we use $.grep to filter out undefined.

Comment: Nice...was wondering what the $.grep was for. Thanks, have learnt a few tricks on looping arrays and objects

Answer (score 0):

Try below code using `for` loop makes easier.. If your data is in the sequence as mentioned above

```
var data = {
  "menu":
  [    
    {
      "section":"theMobileMenu",
      "key":"menuItem1Title",
      "content":"Mobile context and principles"
    },
    {
      "section":"theMobileMenu",
      "key":"menuItem1Link",
      "content":"/mobile/index.html"
    },
    {
      "section":"theMobileMenu",
      "key":"menuItem2Title",
      "content":"Global guidelines"
    },
    {
      "section":"theMobileMenu",
      "key":"menuItem2Link",
      "content":"/mobile/global-guidelines.html"
    },
    {
      "section":"theMobileMenu",
      "key":"menuItem3Title",
      "content":"First impressions"
    },
    {
      "section":"theMobileMenu",
      "key":"menuItem3Link",
      "content":"/mobile/first-impressions.html"
    }
  ]
};

var newData = [];
var curData = {};
var menu = data.menu;

for(i=0, j=1; i < menu.length; i+=2, j++){
    if(menu[i]['key'] == "menuItem"+j+"Title"){
       curData.title = menu[i]['content'];       
       if($.isPlainObject(menu[i+1]) && menu[i+1]['key'] == "menuItem"+j+"Link"){
         curData.link = menu[i+1]['content'];       
       }
       newData.push(curData);
    }
    curData = {};
} 
console.log(newData);
```

Output :

```
[
   {
     "title":"Mobile context and principles",
     "link":"/mobile/index.html"
   },
  {
    "title":"Global guidelines",
    "link":"/mobile/global-guidelines.html"
  },
  {
    "title":"First impressions",
    "link":"/mobile/first-impressions.html"
  }
]
```

Comment: This returns a blank array

Comment: Please find below Fiddle URL

Comment: did you get the solution?

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for any order with a temporary object and some regular expressions for matching key, title and link.

```js
var object = { menu: [{ "section": "theMobileMenu", "key": "menuItem1Title", "content": "Mobile context and principles" }, { "section": "theMobileMenu", "key": "menuItem1Link", "content": "/mobile/index.html" }, { "section": "theMobileMenu", "key": "menuItem2Title", "content": "Global guidelines" }, { "section": "theMobileMenu", "key": "menuItem2Link", "content": "/mobile/global-guidelines.html" }, { "section": "theMobileMenu", "key": "menuItem3Title", "content": "First impressions" }, { "section": "theMobileMenu", "key": "menuItem3Link", "content": "/mobile/first-impressions.html" }] },
    result = function (array) {
        var temp = {}
        array.forEach(function (a) {
            var k = a.key.match(/^menuItem\d*/);
            temp[k] = temp[k] || {};
            temp[k][a.key.match(/(Title)|(Link)$/)[0].toLowerCase()] = a.content;
        });
        return Object.keys(temp).map(function (k) { return temp[k]; });
    }(object.menu);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

**https://jsfiddle.net/VixedS/01x2a8jp/**

```
var oldData = {menu:[{ "section": "theMobileMenus", "key": "menuItem1Title", "content": "Mobile context and principles" }, { "section": "theMobileMenu", "key": "menuItem1Link", "content": "/mobile/index.html" }, { "section": "theMobileMenu", "key": "menuItem2Title", "content": "Global guidelines" }, { "section": "theMobileMenu", "key": "menuItem2Link", "content": "/mobile/global-guidelines.html" }, { "section": "theMobileMenu", "key": "menuItem3Title", "content": "First impressions" }, { "section": "theMobileMenu", "key": "menuItem3Link", "content": "/mobile/first-impressions.html"}]};

var newData = []
$.each(oldData.menu, function(i, val){
    if (this.key.indexOf('Link') > -1)
        newData.push({'title':this.section,'link':this.content});
});

newData=JSON.stringify(newData);
```